# OutOfMemoryError (Java) : Java heap space

Tags: java, r, excel, out-of-memory, xlconnect

I'm trying to add 10 more rows at the end of an excel table (currently 27k rows long)

```
options(java.parameters = "-Xmx4g" ) ; 
library(XLConnect) ;
writeWorksheetToFile("H:/R/myfile.xlsx",DataTable,sheet="Sheet1",startRow=row1,startCol=1,header=FALSE,rownames=FALSE)
```

after some seconds I receive the error

OutOfMemoryError (Java) : Java heap space

How can I fix this? Shouldn't options(java.parameters = "-Xmx4g" ) work?

Comment: `Shouldn't options ... work?` ... not if what you are trying to do exceeds available heap space.  What version of Java are you using (e.g. 64 bit Java 8)?

Comment: With  `options(java.parameters = "-Xmx512m")` it doesn't work ? For your data which are weak in bytes, it should be enough. If you exceed heap space, maybe the value it is not considered. Try to use jvisualvm or similar tools to check the memory is suitably configured at the runtime

Comment: Try using `java.parameters = "-Xmx8g"`

Comment: Why not have Java call R script as a subprocess?

Comment: HI Tim Biegeleisen, I have version 8.

Answer (score 1):

Try using openxlsx package.  I had problems with XLConnect and Java.

Comment: I quite like XLconnect, but I'm giving up because of non deterministic errors that always pop up. Now executing `m=matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),3); writeWorksheetToFile("H:/R/m.xlsx",m,sheet="Sheet1",rownames=FALSE) ;` gives me `Error: ClassCastException (Java): org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlComplexContentImpl cannot be cast to org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTWorkbookPr` of course if I run the same code on another istance of R it works perfectly.

Comment: HI @DataMunger I'm trying to use openxlsx but I receive error "Try installr::install.rtools() on Windows".  If I try that, I receive an even more misterious "Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘installr’" and I'm not able to find this rtools in the package list. What I'm supposed to do to perform any activity with openslsx?

Comment: You can find Rtools at

setup_rtools {devtools} R Documentation
Find rtools.

Description

To build binary packages on windows, Rtools (found at http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) needs to be on the path. The default installation process does not add it, so this script finds it (looking first on the path, then in the registry). It also checks that the version of rtools matches the version of R.

Usage

setup_rtools(cache = TRUE, debug = FALSE)

This should allow you to install Rtools and then you should be good to go with openxlsx.